# How can I create a meta_query to find data that matches a range of values?

Tags: php, wordpress

With these two objects:

```
[{
  name: "Item 1",
  weight_min: 16,
  weight_max: 22
},{
  name: "Item 2",
  weight_min: 14,
  weight_max: 20
}]
```

and this meta query:

```
$weight = explode(',', $_GET['weight']);

$args['meta_query'][] = array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'key' => 'weight_min',
    'value' => array($weight[0], $weight[1]),
    'type' => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
  ),
  array(
    'key' => 'weight_max',
    'value' => array($weight[0], $weight[1]),
    'type' => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
  )
);
```

It works in that it checks both the min_weight and the max_weight and provides all results that match, but what I need is for it to return the objects with values that fall BETWEEN the weight_min and weight_max. 
For example, if I run `&weight=0,18`, it will return both objects. If I run, `&weight=10,15` it will return the second object. But if I search for anything that falls between weight_min and weight_max like `&weight=17,19`, I want both of the objects to return because 17-19 falls between the weight_min and weight_max for both.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ??

```
array(($weight[0]-1), ($weight[1]+1)),
```

Comment: I don't think so. The issue isn't that I need to check a wider range, it's that I need any values *between* the two array values to be a true match.